# Passing two or more parameters to Oracle SQL

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I'm trying to define a list of values (id numbers) for two parameters and pass them to SQL that's querying Oracle tables.

This code works as long as I only include one id and one parameter

```
idlist = ['SLCTD']
in_vars = ','.join(':%d' % i for i in range(len(idlist)))
query = """
select PEBEMPL_ECLS_CODE 
from PEBEMPL
inner join SPRIDEN on spriden_pidm = pebempl_pidm 
where SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
and SPRIDEN_ID in (%s)
""" % in_vars
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection, params=idlist)
```

Now have tried the following with two parameters and failed:

```
idlist = [735,'SLCTD']
in_vars = ','.join(':%d' % i for i in range(len(idlist)))
query = """
select PEBEMPL_ECLS_CODE 
from PEBEMPL
inner join SPRIDEN on spriden_pidm = pebempl_pidm 
where SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
and PLANNING_WEEK in (%s)
and SPRIDEN_ID in (%s)
""" % in_vars
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection, params=idlist)
```

Please advise

Comment: *And failed* - please, paste the error you get. Your error is not related to SQL, string formatting failed, because you pass only one argument when there are two placeholders. So the real question is: *How to format string with two arguments*

Comment: You can't concatenate bind variables into a single bind variable and pass that to an IN operator in oracle. IN (:B) will only take the entire string into account. If you have multiple values in the IN operator, then each of those will have to be passed as a separated bind variable. Like this: IN (:B1,:B2,:B3)

Comment: @koenlostrie The above code is supposed to generate as much unnamed variables as there are elements in the list, so in `execute` the statement will have enough bind variables to bind. The problem is in string interpolation

Comment: The error occurs on line "and SPRIDEN_ID in (%s) """ % in_vars. The error message is "not enough arguments for format string.". Note: This query is inside a Python3 script.

Comment: For future readers, cx_Oracle documentation on [Binding Multiple Values to a SQL WHERE IN Clause](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause) may be useful.

Comment: The solution for you is to use named parameters in string interpolation: `"... and PLANNING_WEEK in ({L})
and SPRIDEN_ID in ({L})".format(L=in_vars)` Then you'll need to repeat the same variables in substitution part multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has the following:

If you execute the script from tty you need to do:

```
sqlplus $USER/$PASSWD @file.sql param_1 param_2
```

Into the file.sql you may have:

```
SELECT '$1', '$2' FROM DUAL;
```

Where $1 is the first parameter and $2 the second, if you want more, you can put as many parameters as you want.

If you are calling your script from python.
You must to:

```
python3 file.py param_1 param_2 ... param_n
```

into file.py

```
import sys
sys.argv[1] --> param_1
sys.argv[2] --> param_2
sys.argv[n] --> param_n
```

Answer (score 0):

For the string formatting issue, try something like [this](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#2-new-style-string-formatting-strformat) with Python 3:

```py
idlist = ['SLCTD']
in_vars = ','.join(':bv%d' % i for i in range(len(idlist)))
query = """
select PEBEMPL_ECLS_CODE 
from PEBEMPL
inner join SPRIDEN on spriden_pidm = pebempl_pidm 
where SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
and PLANNING_WEEK in ({})
and SPRIDEN_ID in ({})
""".format(in_vars,in_vars)

print(query)
```

The output is:

```
select PEBEMPL_ECLS_CODE 
from PEBEMPL
inner join SPRIDEN on spriden_pidm = pebempl_pidm 
where SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
and PLANNING_WEEK in (:bv0)
and SPRIDEN_ID in (:bv0)
```

Since you are reusing bind variable "names" (the bv0), you will need to do 'bind by name' when you execute, which I will leave as an exercise for you to do.

Comment: Thank you Christopher. Your solution works for me although it seems somewhat counter intuitive. I kept the original pd.read.sql statement intact although id_list now contains more than one parameter. I assume that you could expand this to three or more parameters.